# MATLAB Timer in GUI not updating the plot

Tags: matlab, plot, timer, matlab-guide

I am trying to make an animation of a line in the MATLAB GUIDE. I am trying to use a timer to update the plot.

The following is my code for the timer.

```
handles.startPos = -2.5;
handles.line_init =0;
cla(handles.axes1);
guidata(hObject, handles);
handles.timer = timer('Period', 1.0 / 2, ...
                          'TimerFcn', @(~,~)update_line(handles.startPos,hObject), ...
                          'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate');
```

The following is the code for my *update_line* function

```
function p = update_line(x_cor,hObject)
handles = guidata(hObject);
if (handles.line_init==1)
    delete(handles.line)
end
axes(handles.axes1)
p = plot3([handles.startPos handles.startPos+0.5],[0 0],[0 0],'r','LineWidth',4);
handles.line = p;
handles.line_init=1;
disp(handles.startPos)
handles.startPos = handles.startPos+0.5;
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

The variable *"handles.startPos"* is getting updated. But the plot is not getting updated. It is just showing the plot with the initial value of the *"handles.startPos"*, and not the updated one. But if I stop and start the timer again, the plot update with the new value of *"handles.startPos"*. But then again it doesn't get updated and it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting the timer?

```
start(handles.timer)
```

In addition, the code wont run as is - what is handles.axes1 set to?

If I use the following, it works for me:

```
 handles.axes1 = 0
 handles.startPos = -2.5;
 handles.line_init =0;
 cla(handles.axes1);
 hObject = figure
 handles.axes1 = gca
 guidata(hObject, handles);
 handles.timer = timer('Period', 1.0 / 2, ...
                      'TimerFcn', @(~,~)update_line(handles.startPos,hObject), ...
                      'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate');
 start(handles.timer)
```

Comment: My timer is running, because I am displaying the "handles.startPos" and I can see that the value is getting updated

Comment: I noticed something, if I plot in a figure in a separate window. It is getting updated. But the figure in my GUI is not getting updated.

Comment: I solved it by adding set(p,'Parent', handles.axes1). But now an empty figure pops up, but the animation is working.

Comment: how about caling refresh ?

Comment: How do I call refresh?

Comment: I tried using drawnow(). Sometimes it works, and on other occasions, it starts plotting data on a new figure